# Form php (Laravel)

Tags: php, forms, laravel

**I have one view and inside this view i have a form with a select option and one button to request some data**. Depending on the option chosen (The data came from my rest -> this part is not important for my question) i show to the user some information.

**So when i click on the request button i need go to my function, get the return data** (checking which option you choose is not important right now) **and send again to the same view and show to the user in specific div**. I already implement forms that connect to my function get the data and return to other view with the request data. But in this case it is different and **i need to connect to function and show the return data but staying the same view.**

Thanks for the help.

Regards

EDIT (more information)

My view (Action in form i need to do something to connect to my function in controller and get the data). For example if i choose the "Data1" my function return a json or array with the data about data 1, and i need to show this information in the same view in "mydiv".
In my controller i have a simple function that return some data (in this case to test it can be a simple string)

```
    <div id="mydiv">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="">
          <select size ="1" name="selectData" style="height:30px;">
            <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
            <option value="data1">Data 1</option>
            <option value="data2">Data 2</option>
          </select>
        </form>
     ***SHOW STRING (DATA 1) HERE***
    </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="request" style="float: center;">
     Request
   </button>
```

Comment: Please show us the code you already have and a specific example of what you want exactly.

Comment: please show some code to help you more

Comment: i add one example for my view, thanks

Comment: In my controller i have a simple function that return some data (in this case to test it can be a simple string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve what you are looking for by making an ajax call .. here is the simple demo ..
this is your blade file code

```
<div id="mydiv">
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="">
        <select size ="1" name="selectData" style="height:30px;">
            <option value="0" style="display:none;"></option>
            <option value="data1">Data 1</option>
            <option value="data2">Data 2</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="response"></div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="request" style="float: center;">
    Request
</button>
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="selectData"]').change(function () {
            var selectData = $('select[name="selectData"]').val();
            if (selectData != 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/getinfo',
                    data: {
                        '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}',
                        'selectData': selectData,
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (json) {
                        $('#response').text(json);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is your route

```
Route::post('/getinfo', 'HomeController@getinfo');
```

create getinfo method in your HomeController

```
public function getinfo(){
        $data = Input::get('selectData');
        $msg ='';
        if($data=='data1'){
            $msg = "data 1 selected";
        }else if($data=='data2'){
            $msg = "data 2 selected";
        }
        return response()->json($msg);
    }
```

if you want to get the response from controller after button click you may use like this

```
$('#request').click(function () {
            var selectData = $('select[name="selectData"]').val();
            if (selectData != 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/getinfo',
                    data: {
                        '_token': '{{csrf_token()}}',
                        'selectData': selectData,
                    },
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (json) {
                        $('#response').text(json);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

hope this will help.

Comment: Hi. First of all thanks for the help. I got it, but it is not working :x

Comment: If i use the first script the browser return this error:
http://localhost:8000/getinfo Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 

But i add the route

If i use the second script and click on button i dont have any error but the msg is not appear

Comment: I found the problem now.. in getinfo function the Input not working. so i change the function to this:
public function getinfo(Request $request)
  {
    //$data = Input::get('selectData');
     $data = $request->get('selectData');


i receive the request and read the request from select option and it's work :)  Thanks a lot for the help! Best regards :)